# Modify a value inside a node in standalone.xml (Wildfly Java API)

Tags: java, wildfly-10

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Hi everyone, can anybody help me? I am trying to change the value in

```
<root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
```

from name=INFO to name=DEBUG. Currently i have the following Java code

```
private ModelNode changeRootLooger(){
    ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set(ClientConstants.WRITE_ATTRIBUTE_OPERATION);
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem", "logging");
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("root-logger");
    request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("level");
    request.get("name").set("name");  
    request.get("value").set("DEBUG");  
    return request;
}
```

but so far it does not work. The Wildfly API documentaion is too obscure for me. 
I always get the following exception.

```
Result logger:
```

{
    "outcome" : "failed",
    "failure-description" : "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [\n    (\"subsystem\" => \"logging\"),\n    (\"root-logger\" => \"level\")\n]",
    "rolled-back" : true
}

Please Help me, I've been working the whole day with this problem

Comment: Better ;-) ... and then delete those comments that dont make sense any more ;-)